# Connecting Xampp to FastAPI with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have been using the sqlalchemy for FastAPI. I will be using MySQL in XAMPP.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
import mysql.connector
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "mysql+mysqlconnector://root@localhost/fastapi"
db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    username='root',
    password='',
    database='fastapi'

)
engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL
)
meta= MetaData()
conn = engine.connect()
```

Should I add the port or not?

Comment: Why are you using both ´mysql.connector` and SQLAlchemy? And for the port - if it's different than the default, include it - just try it and see if it works. If it doesn't, include your error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

# engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:password@localhost:3005/doctors_appoinment')

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "mysql+mysqlconnector://root:@localhost:3306/doctors_appoinment"

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL,
)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

meta = MetaData()

conn = engine.connect()

Base = declarative_base()
```

You can use this code for connection.
And you can mention your port using this.